# print ftp files in list view

Tags: android, ftp, bundle

I m developing a app that downloads list of files from ftp server. the file names are downloaded using array. how can i pass this array to main activity and display it in a list view.i have a very little knowledge in this domain so kind of help is appreciated.thanking you in advance

```
     FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles("/public_html/");
        int length = ftpFiles.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
            boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile(); 
                if (isFile) {

                            Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);


            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ListView widget. The simplest way of displaying a list of items in a list view would be to use predefined ArrayAdapter class and an existing Android layout for the rows. Please check this tutorial for detailed explanation how to use ListView.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html